# Restoring a Back Up File to a Different App Service from Azure

Tags: azure, backup

I successfully created a backup file from my first app service using an [Azure feature.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-backup/)
Is it possible to restore the backup file to another app service?

If not, is there a way to download the backup file, upload then extract it to the other app service? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can restore a backup of a web app to another one. But, you need to do more than just clicking the **Restore Now** button.

1. Log into the new Portal, on the **Settings** blade of your web app, click **Backups**, choose the backup you want to restore, and copy the file location. It would look like this:

   ```
   https://<your storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your container>?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=fieQjleVYxDuXG2Ym8yjPpbdPxHOnbiLo8HcRuxyluw%3D&st=2016-04-05T02%3A35%3A25Z&se=2290-01-18T02%3A35%3A25Z&sp=rwdl
   ```
2. From the above URL, you can format a link to download the backup file, by adding the file name after the container name. Here is a link to the zip file:

   ```
   https://<your storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your container>/<your web app>.zip?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=fieQjleVYxDuXG2Ym8yjPpbdPxHOnbiLo8HcRuxyluw%3D&st=2016-04-05T02%3A35%3A25Z&se=2290-01-18T02%3A35%3A25Z&sp=rwdl
   ```
3. Download the files with the above link. You get a zip file. Since you are restoring it to a different web app, you can ignore the xml and the log files.
4. Unzip the zip file, and you will see a .bacpac file, a meta file, and a "fs" folder. You can ignore the meta file.
5. You can use Visual Studio or SSMS to restore the .bacpac file to a database linked to your new web app.
6. For files inside the "fs" folder, you can use a ftp client to upload it to your new web app. Don't forget to change the connection string, before uploading.

In fact, it's quite complicated. If you are just restoring a quite recent version of your web app. I suggest you skip step 6, and use your most favorite deploy method to deploy it to you new web app.

If you just want to clone a web app, you can do it through the new portal. For more information, see [Azure App Service App Cloning Using Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-app-cloning-portal/)

Comment: This worked for me. I so would have cloned it, but that's only available on the Azure Premium tariff.

Comment: Unfortunately when I unzip the backup zip file, the original directory structure is not recreated.